# MVC 4 Minification does not work properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, bundling-and-minification

Using this source code, the minification of a file isn't working.  It works if I remove the line `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`  which does not minify the files.

Overall, bundling is working since script, CSS and LESS files are loaded properly when `EnableOptimization` is set to false. I don't understand why it's not working. Below is my code for bundling CSS, Javascript, and LESS files.

```
var defaultCss = new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css")
    .Include("~/Static/css/bootstrap.css",
             "~/Static/css/bootstrap-responsive.css",
             "~/Static/css/media.css",
             "~/Static/css/style.css",
             "~/Static/css/editmode.css",
             "~/Static/less/framework.less",
             "~/Static/less/navigation.less",
             "~/Static/less/variables.less");

defaultCss.Transforms.Add(new LessMinify());
defaultCss.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
bundles.Add(defaultCss);

var defaultJss = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js")
    .Include("~/Static/js/jquery.js",
             "~/Static/js/bootstrap.js",
             "~/Static/js/site.js",
             "~/Static/js/modernizr.js");

defaultJss.Transforms.Add(new JsMinify());
bundles.Add(defaultJss);
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

if one of the files in the list is missing or has a syntax error, the bundle does not get generated. I think!

Maybe your site.js is missing a comma or something like that. Why don't you try moving it below modernizr?

Comment: The code is getting generated and also no syntax error.I rechecked all the file 3 times.(page source and clicked the code for css and js)All files are there. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I was actually referring the same script twice and Hence my Page css was getting disturbed. Removed the duplicate reference and Its works now.